# 2 axis plot with SciDraw

Tags: plotting, scidraw

What is the best way to include the [2 axis plot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales.html) in Scidraw? I need it as one of a bunch of multipanel figures and when I include it with `FigGraphics` the second Y axis is lost. I can manually use `TickLabelFunction` to restore the correct ticks, but this is very tedious.

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to answer this one while writing the question, and thought I would share the answer. Scidraw makes it super easy to do 2 axis plots!

````
a = Plot[1000*x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
b = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Figure[Multipanel[{FigurePanel[{
     FigGraphics@a;
     }, {1, 1}, XPlotRange -> {0, 1}, YPlotRange -> {0, 1000}, 
    ShowTickLabels -> {{False, True}, {True, False}},
    YTickTextColor -> Blue],
   FigurePanel[{
     FigGraphics@b;
     }, {1, 1}, XPlotRange -> {0, 1}, YPlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
    ShowTickLabels -> {{True, False}, {False, False}},
    YTickTextColor -> Red
    
    
    ]}, Dimensions -> {1, 1}, XPanelGaps -> 0.2, YPanelGaps -> 0.2, 
  ShowFrameLabel -> True,(*by default we want all frame labels,
  not just on the edges*)
  ShowTickLabels -> True], CanvasSize -> {8, 6}]
```
````